# How to select the dropdownlist value and validate it

Tags: php, html

I have created the dropdown list in my index page i want to select the one value from that list and validate it if not selected any value the code for that is as follows:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <select value="state" name="state">
    <option selected="">---please enter---</option>
    <option value="1">andhra</option>
    <option value="2">thamil</option>
    <option value="3">kerela</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

php code for the above file is as follows:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['state'])) {
  $state = $_POST['state'];
}
else {
  echo "required";
}
?>
```

I dont want to be select the first option in selection list please enter to be selected but the code which I have used is taking that value also I want relevant code how to validate that list?

Comment: Huh? Can you type this again in clear, concise words?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer adding a `disabled` attribute to the placeholder option, that way, a user has to choose something if they click the drop-down:

```
<select value="state" name="state">
    <option selected disabled>---please enter---</option>
    <option value="1">andhra</option>
    <option value="2">thamil</option>
    <option value="3">kerela</option>
</select>
```

Quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hxxJZ/

Answer (score 0):

something like this should to the trick:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <select name="state">
    <option value="0" selected>---please enter---</option>
    <option value="1">andhra</option>
    <option value="2">thamil</option>
    <option value="3">kerela</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

php

```
<?php
if( 0 != $_POST['state'] ) {
  $state = $_POST['state'];
}
else {
  echo "required";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

your HTML is not right,
try edit this line

```
<option selected=""...
```

to this one

```
<option selected value="">---
```

Answer (score 0):

`select` elements do not have an (HTML) value attribute, so remove `value="state"`.

The `selected` attribute should be `selected="selected"` (or just `SELECTED`).